# Unable to use 2 popovers in a single view

Tags: swift, swiftui, popover

I created a new Single View App in Xcode 11.4.1 that uses Swift and SwiftUI. The project has 2 buttons with the options to show either popover 1 or popover 2. I don't receive any errors but only popover 2 works. My code is below.

I tried rearranging the position of the popover code but it did not make a difference. If the popover 1 code appears after the popover 2 code then only popover 1 works (instead of only having popover 2 work).

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {

    @State var popover1IsVisible = false
    @State var popover2IsVisible = false

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button(action: {
                self.popover1IsVisible = true
            }) {
                Text("Show Popover 1")
            }

            Button(action: {
                self.popover2IsVisible = true
            }) {
                Text("Show Popover 2")
            }
        }

        .popover(isPresented: $popover1IsVisible) {
            VStack {
                Text("Popover1")
                Button(action: {
                    self.popover1IsVisible = false
                }) {
                    Text("OK")
                }
            }
        }

        .popover(isPresented: $popover2IsVisible) {
            VStack {
                Text("Popover 2")
                Button(action: {
                    self.popover2IsVisible = false
                }) {
                    Text("OK")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can not add `.popover` twice to the view. Try to use it once and build the popover view dynamically depending on which button was clicked.

```
struct ContentView: View {

    @State var showPopover = false
    @State var popover1IsVisible : Bool = false
    @State var popover2IsVisible : Bool = false

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button(action: {
                self.showPopover = true
                self.popover1IsVisible = true
            }) {
                Text("Show Popover 1")
            }

            Button(action: {
                self.showPopover = true
                self.popover2IsVisible = true
            }) {
                Text("Show Popover 2")
            }
        }
        .popover(isPresented: $showPopover) {
            VStack {
                if (self.popover1IsVisible)
                {
                    //Show first view
                    Text("Popover1")
                    Button(action: {
                        self.showPopover = false
                        self.popover1IsVisible = false
                    }) {
                        Text("OK")
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    //Show secondview
                    Text("Popover 2")
                    Button(action: {
                        self.showPopover = false
                        self.popover2IsVisible = false
                    }) {
                        Text("OK")
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: That really helped me! Thank you! I put the popover in generic view then manipulate variable according to which button is clicked

Comment: How would you make the popover point to the "Show Popover 2" button?

Answer (score 2):

You can't attach two popovers to one view (VStack). Attach each popover to different views. You can attach `.popover` to `Button`.